# How do I properly use org.apache.commons.codec.digest.Md5Crypt?

Tags: java, encryption

I have a question on the correct usage of org.apache.commons.codec.digest.Md5Cryp.
In the jar you can find the method

```
public static String md5Crypt(final byte[] keyBytes)
```

which generates internally a random salt and then returns an encrypted string.
But I wonder what benefit this function should have because I will never be able to retreive the same encrypted string again without knowing the salt.
On the other hand the library does not offer a method like getRandomSalt().
Could anybody please point to how one should use this library?

Comment: All methods in this class refer to [Crypt.crypt(String,String)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/Crypt.html) method for details, where the structure of the output string is defined.

Answer (score 1):

To verify a value you've encrypted with `md5Crypt`, use the `md5Crypt(byte[], String)` method where the String is the encrypted value you already have, then compare the two encrypted Strings to see if they're the same.

```
String somevalue = "somevalue"; 
String encrypted1 = Md5Crypt.md5Crypt(somevalue.getBytes());
String encrypted2 = Md5Crypt.md5Crypt(somevalue.getBytes(), encrypted1);
String encrypted3 = Md5Crypt.md5Crypt(somevalue.getBytes());
System.out.println("encrypted1==encrypted2: " + encrypted1.equals(encrypted2));
System.out.println("encrypted1==encrypted3: " + encrypted1.equals(encrypted3));

Output:
encrypted1==encrypted2: true
encrypted1==encrypted3: false
```

Internally md5Crypt is extracting the salt value from the encrypted String you pass in to the `md5Crypt(byte[], String)` method.

Also, I don't know what your use case is, but if this is for storage of any type of credentials I'd recommend using `SHA512` contained in the Apache commons `Sha2Crypt` class, (or better yet) `PBKDF2` or `bCrypt`. MD5 is a fairly fast hashing algorithm and was not designed to be used for hashing passwords. It's speed makes it good for things like file integrity verification, but bad for password hashing even with a salt.

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer, it's so easy (my god!):
The returned string contains the salt, e.g.:

> $1$XYpZthWO$RHlJfrViJBZAOTRrGXRki/

The $ sign is the separator for the string parts ...